# How can I change DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS while configuring Spring WebClient proxy?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am trying to configure WebClient with proxy the next way (kotlin):

```
private fun WebClient.Builder.securedHttpConnector(
    host: String,
    port: Int,
    sslContextBuilder: SslContextBuilder
) =
    apply {
        clientConnector(
            ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                HttpClient
                    .create()
                    .secure { sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContextBuilder) }
                    .tcpConfiguration { tcpClient ->
                        tcpClient.proxy {
                            it
                                .type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP)
                                .address(InetSocketAddress(host, port))
                        }
                    }
            )
        )
    }
```

But default timout in the ProxyHandler.java is 10000 millis. How can I change it? The partner system gives a response for a long time that is more then 10s and I recieve the following exception:

```
io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyConnectException: http, none, /<proxy host>:<proxy port> => /<target host>:<target port>, timeout
at io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyHandler$2.run(ProxyHandler.java:201) ~[netty-handler-proxy-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38) ~[netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:127) ~[netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) ~[netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java) ~[netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:405) ~[netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:906) ~[netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the option ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS see [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-builder-reactor-timeout)

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this works without proxy. The ProxyHandler has its own timeout field connectTimeoutMillis